# Does adding a star after a pointer struct definition make it a double pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have a struct

```
typedef struct hash_entry_{
   char *string;
   void *data;
   struct hash_entry *next;
}hash_entry, *p_entry;
```

I am referencing `p_entry` later in my code like so,

```
p_entry *temp = table;
```

does this make temp a double-pointer since I am adding an extra `*` before `p_entry`. I am confused on the point of even adding `p_entry` in my code when I can use `hash_entry*` as a pointer to a struct of `hash_entry_` type.

Comment: Yes, it does. And the confusion you're experiencing is part and parcel with why hiding pointer-types in typedef aliases is nearly *always* a *bad* idea. Had your declaration been simply `hash_entry **temp = table;` the presence of a pointer-to-pointer would have been crystal clear.

Comment: If you don't know, you can ask gdb what type something is with `ptype` or `whatis`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this make temp a double-pointer

Yes it does. But please use the term pointer-to-pointer, not to confuse things with `double*`.

The manner of "Hungarian notation" and other confused styles where you add a `p` in front of a type name to indicate that a pointer was hidden beneath it has been massively criticised over the years, the most well-known case is the Windows API. This is old, bad style that refuses to die.

In modern programming, there is a strong C programmer consensus that:

- Pointers should never be hidden underneath `typedef` because it's very confusing for everyone including the person who wrote the code, as you found out.
- "Hungarian notation" and similar styles should not be used since they are confusing and dangerous.

You instinct of using `hash_entry*` instead is sound.